# How to get each table row result in new list? Python webscraping

Tags: python, regex, list, for-loop, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape company information from a public [website](https://www.afm.nl/nl-nl/sector/registers/vergunningenregisters/financiele-dienstverleners/details?id=C18B1D63-774C-E811-80D9-005056BB0C82). Two questions:

1. The link of each subpage is very long and complex. For example: https://link/details?id=535145A8-E3FA-DF11-BB5A-005056BE6692 with a different ID for each subpage. Is there an easier way to scrape each subpage than to use regex to come up with different versions of the url? (re.findall("\w*-\w*-\w*-\w*-\w*")). It might be a bit heavy on the system.
2. I'm trying to get every row from the table in a new list. However, my code is now putting all table data in one long list. How to receive the data per row? I can't get it to work.

Thank you for thinking along!
Ps. I work in PyCharm with Python version 3.11

This is how the part of my code looks like right now:

```
# Scrape and find table content
table_results = soup.find_all('tbody')

# Loop over table, get the text content following the span element within the table data, and add it to the final list
for tr in table_results:
    data = []
    for td in tr.find_all('td'):
        for span in td.find_all('span', class_='cc-mobile-title'):
            # Extract the text content after the span element within the td
            text_content = span.next_sibling
            data.append(text_content)

    register.append(data)
    
print(register)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is and example how you can get the data from the page (table, title,...) into a pandas dataframe and then automatically follow the next link:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.afm.nl/nl-nl/sector/registers/vergunningenregisters/financiele-dienstverleners/details?id=C18B1D63-774C-E811-80D9-005056BB0C82"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0"
}

all_dfs = []
while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

    for tag in soup.select(".cc-mobile-title"):
        tag.extract()

    df = pd.read_html(StringIO(str(soup)))[0]
    df["title"] = soup.h1.get_text(strip=True)

    for label, value in zip(
        soup.select(".cc-em--detail-list__label"),
        soup.select(".cc-em--detail-list__value"),
    ):
        df[label.get_text(strip=True)] = value.get_text(strip=True)

    print(df)
    all_dfs.append(df)

    next_url = soup.select_one('a:-soup-contains("Volgende register resultaat")')
    if not next_url:
        break

    url = "https://www.afm.nl/" + next_url["href"]

final_df = pd.concat(all_dfs)
print(final_df)
final_df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Prints:

```
  Financiele Dienst                          Product   Begindatum  Einddatum         title Statutaire naam   Handelsnaam Vergunningnummer                                                                          0         Adviseren            Inkomensverzekeringen  01 jan 2006        NaN  Michal Tomeš    Michal Tomeš  Michal Tomeš         12045811
1         Adviseren  Schadeverzekeringen particulier  01 jan 2006        NaN  Michal Tomeš    Michal Tomeš  Michal Tomeš         12045811                                                                          2         Adviseren     Schadeverzekeringen zakelijk  01 jan 2006        NaN  Michal Tomeš    Michal Tomeš  Michal Tomeš         12045811
3         Adviseren                         Vermogen  01 jan 2006        NaN  Michal Tomeš    Michal Tomeš  Michal Tomeš         12045811
4        Bemiddelen            Inkomensverzekeringen  01 jan 2006        NaN  Michal Tomeš    Michal Tomeš  Michal Tomeš         12045811
5        Bemiddelen  Schadeverzekeringen particulier  01 jan 2006        NaN  Michal Tomeš    Michal Tomeš  Michal Tomeš         12045811
6        Bemiddelen     Schadeverzekeringen zakelijk  01 jan 2006        NaN  Michal Tomeš    Michal Tomeš  Michal Tomeš         12045811
7        Bemiddelen                         Vermogen  01 jan 2006        NaN  Michal Tomeš    Michal Tomeš  Michal Tomeš         12045811
  Financiele Dienst                          Product   Begindatum  Einddatum         title Statutaire naam   Handelsnaam Vergunningnummer
0         Adviseren            Inkomensverzekeringen  01 jan 2007        NaN  Michal Treml    Michal Treml  Michal Treml         12045973
1         Adviseren  Schadeverzekeringen particulier  01 jan 2007        NaN  Michal Treml    Michal Treml  Michal Treml         12045973
2         Adviseren     Schadeverzekeringen zakelijk  01 jan 2007        NaN  Michal Treml    Michal Treml  Michal Treml         12045973

...
```

The `final_df` at the end concatenates all DataFrames to one final dataframe.